# Python - Is there a way to use a greater than operator that is not a comparison operator?

Tags: python, operators, python-3.6, comparison-operators

I am trying to make a program that only prints positions in a string that is greater than this position in the string, first i tried the > but it comes up with "Invalid syntax" and highlights it in red. I tried the comparison greater than but that does the same thing (Because i am not comparing)
What i have tried:

```
sentence = ("Mark")
print (sentence[> 1])
```

What i want it to print:
rk

If you have any solutions or alternatives to a greater than operator in Python please let me know and i will give it a go. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is `print (sentence[2:])`
For future reference and research, it is called slice.